# How to understand tensorflow error message?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I found that the error message from TensorFlow, especially at *run time* (i.e. in `sess.run()`). There'is few document explaining how to understand the error message.

For example, there is a error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 10669 values, but the requested shape has 11172
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/RPNloss/cond/calcRPNLoss/calcAllRPNLosses/classification_loss/Reshape_2_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/RPNloss/cond/calcRPNLoss/calcAllRPNLosses/classification_loss/Reshape_2_grad/Reshape/tensor, optimizer/gradients/RPNloss/cond/calcRPNLoss/calcAllRPNLosses/classification_loss/Reshape_2_grad/Shape)]]
     [[Node: cond/getRefinementLoss/posLoss/getPosLoss/Reshape/_1897 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4151_cond/getRefinementLoss/posLoss/getPosLoss/Reshape", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hyh/projects/RFCN-tensorflow/main.py", line 155, in <module>
    res = runManager.modRun(i)
  File "/home/hyh/projects/RFCN-tensorflow/Utils/RunManager.py", line 97, in modRun
    return self.runAndMerge(feed_dict, options=options if options is not None else self.options, run_metadata=run_metadata if run_metadata is not None else self.run_metadata)
  File "/home/hyh/projects/RFCN-tensorflow/Utils/RunManager.py", line 71, in runAndMerge
    res = self.sess.run(self.inputTensors, feed_dict=feed_dict, options=options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 10669 values, but the requested shape has 11172
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/RPNloss/cond/calcRPNLoss/calcAllRPNLosses/classification_loss/Reshape_2_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/RPNloss/cond/calcRPNLoss/calcAllRPNLosses/classification_loss/Reshape_2_grad/Reshape/tensor, optimizer/gradients/RPNloss/cond/calcRPNLoss/calcAllRPNLosses/classification_loss/Reshape_2_grad/Shape)]]
     [[Node: cond/getRefinementLoss/posLoss/getPosLoss/Reshape/_1897 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4151_cond/getRefinementLoss/posLoss/getPosLoss/Reshape", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'optimizer/gradients/RPNloss/cond/calcRPNLoss/calcAllRPNLosses/classification_loss/Reshape_2_grad/Reshape', defined at:
  File "/home/hyh/projects/RFCN-tensorflow/main.py", line 118, in <module>
    trainOp = createUpdateOp()
  File "/home/hyh/projects/RFCN-tensorflow/main.py", line 104, in createUpdateOp
    grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(totalLoss, var_list=net.getVariables())
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 526, in compute_gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 494, in gradients
    gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 636, in _GradientsHelper
    lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 385, in _MaybeCompile
    return grad_fn()  # Exit early
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 636, in <lambda>
    lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_grad.py", line 521, in _ReshapeGrad
    return [array_ops.reshape(grad, array_ops.shape(op.inputs[0])), None]
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6113, in reshape
    "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

...which was originally created as op 'RPNloss/cond/calcRPNLoss/calcAllRPNLosses/classification_loss/Reshape_2', defined at:
  File "/home/hyh/projects/RFCN-tensorflow/main.py", line 96, in <module>
    tf.losses.add_loss(net.getLoss(boxes, classes))
  File "/home/hyh/projects/RFCN-tensorflow/BoxEngine/BoxNetwork.py", line 50, in getLoss
    return self.rpn.loss(refBoxes) + self.boxRefiner.loss(self.proposals, refBoxes, refClasses)
  File "/home/hyh/projects/RFCN-tensorflow/BoxEngine/RPN.py", line 186, in loss
    return tf.cond(tf.shape(refBoxes)[0] > 0, lambda: calcLoss(), lambda: tf.constant(0.0))
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2063, in cond
    orig_res_t, res_t = context_t.BuildCondBranch(true_fn)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1913, in BuildCondBranch
    original_result = fn()
  File "/home/hyh/projects/RFCN-tensorflow/BoxEngine/RPN.py", line 186, in <lambda>
    return tf.cond(tf.shape(refBoxes)[0] > 0, lambda: calcLoss(), lambda: tf.constant(0.0))
  File "/home/hyh/projects/RFCN-tensorflow/BoxEngine/RPN.py", line 173, in calcLoss
    positiveLosses, negativeLosses = calcAllLosses(inAnchros, inBoxes, inRawSizes, inScores, inBoxSizes)
  File "/home/hyh/projects/RFCN-tensorflow/BoxEngine/RPN.py", line 145, in calcAllLosses
    classificationLoss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=scores, labels=refScores, name="classification_loss")
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1878, in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2
    cost = array_ops.reshape(cost, output_shape)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6113, in reshape
    "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/hyh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 10669 values, but the requested shape has 11172
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/RPNloss/cond/calcRPNLoss/calcAllRPNLosses/classification_loss/Reshape_2_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](optimizer/gradients/RPNloss/cond/calcRPNLoss/calcAllRPNLosses/classification_loss/Reshape_2_grad/Reshape/tensor, optimizer/gradients/RPNloss/cond/calcRPNLoss/calcAllRPNLosses/classification_loss/Reshape_2_grad/Shape)]]
     [[Node: cond/getRefinementLoss/posLoss/getPosLoss/Reshape/_1897 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4151_cond/getRefinementLoss/posLoss/getPosLoss/Reshape", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have two questions:

1. Where there is so many calling stack? First is `Trackback` and then `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`, and `Caused by...`, finally `...which was originally created as op`. What do they mean respectively?
2. Why there is so many error node? In the message above, it seems that there are two nodes that have gone wrong. What does it mean? Which node caused this error?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow error messages are always quite verbose and this is mainly due to how TF works (because of the Computation Graph it builds).
In your case, it seems that you are reshaping a tensor with the wrong shape:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 10669 values, but the requested shape has 11172
```

To see if that is the case try printing the shape of the tensor given to reshape op, i.e.:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
x = tf.layers.dense(input, units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
x = tf.Print(x, [x])
x_rs = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28*28])
```